# How to determine column values changing in a particular direction?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe consisting of 1 column of periods (year and quarters) and another column of some productivity numbers for that period. My task is to identify a period where, for example, I have two consecutive quarters of productivity decline; or, similarly, two consecutive quarters of growth.  I imagine I can use brute force and just loop over the rows looking at several rows at a time, but I was reading that this might have something to do with a "shift" function -- but I dont understand how it works.  Thank you for your help

```
    1971q1  1,137.8
    1971q2  1,159.4
    1971q3  1,180.3
    1971q4  1,173.6
    1972q1  1,163.8
    1972q2  1,140.1
    1972q3  1,145.8
    1972q4  1,150.0
```

Comment: can you [post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40444498/edit) a desired (expected) data set?

Comment: The desired output is not a data set, but a calendar period. The question is: when did the recession begin?  Or, when did the economy come out of recession?

Comment: Can you say what period would it be for your sample (posted) data set? PS the values are constantly growing up...

Comment: Ok, I had fudged the numbers a bit to make my point.  So starting from 1971q1 as the starting point, I go down the column and see that from 1971q3 to 1971q4 and 1971q4 to 1972q1 there are 2 consequtive drops - so thats the start of the recession.  And then I see that, while in the recession, 1972q2 was the lowest point.  And then from 1972q2 and on I had two consequitve periods of growth -- so I am out of the recession.  I dont think that I can computerize it to the point where I magically get the answer, I think if I can generate a column of booleans that let me eyeball the answer, thats good

Comment: I think you will need to think up how your desired data set should look like and post it to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this buddy

```
#define a growth rate
df['growth_rate'] = np.log(df.production) - np.log(df.production).shift(1)
#a recession is when there have been two quarters of negative growth. 
df['recession'] =  (df['growth_rate'] < 0 ) &  (df['growth_rate'].shift(1) < 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's still not quite clear to me how your desired data set should look like.

Here is a method which helps to identify grows and drops:

```
In [450]: df
Out[450]:
   period     val
0  1971q1  1137.8
1  1971q2  1159.4
2  1971q3  1180.3
3  1971q4  1173.6
4  1972q1  1163.8
5  1972q2  1140.1
6  1972q3  1145.8
7  1972q4  1150.0

In [451]: np.sign(df.val.diff().fillna(0))
Out[451]:
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3   -1.0
4   -1.0
5   -1.0
6    1.0
7    1.0
Name: val, dtype: float64

In [452]: df.loc[np.sign(df.val.diff().fillna(0)) < 0]
Out[452]:
   period     val
3  1971q4  1173.6
4  1972q1  1163.8
5  1972q2  1140.1
```